# Cannot add new release for new contrib project

Tags: community-official-site

- I've recently promoted my [project](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_remote_image) from sandbox
- My project's "default branch" is set as `8.x-1.x`
- I've got a tag on my latest commit -- `8.x-1.0-alpha1` -- which is listed on my project's "git tags" area
- As far as I can tell, I've followed the release naming conventions outlined on https://www.drupal.org/node/1015226

However, when I try to follow https://www.drupal.org/node/1068944, I do not see an "add new release" option at the bottom of my project page (or anywhere else). Any suggestions for what I may be doing wrong?

I see that dev releases appear to be generated every 12 hours, but the above has all been set up for longer than 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because on [Media Entity Remote Image](https://www.drupal.org/project/media_entity_remote_image) (the project you linked):

- You **aren't** the project owner

  > [image: screenshot]
- The project owner didn't give you the permission to administer releases

  > [image: screenshot]

As you see in the second screenshot, the checkbox for the *Administer releases* for the *mrweiner* account isn't selected.

If it were, you would see an *Add new release* link right after the *Downlaods* table, which is empty, for the given project.

> [image: screenshot]

If you want to be able to create new releases, you need to get the permission to administer releases too. Otherwise, the project owner needs to create the new release.

*[**Disclaimer**: On Drupal.org I have more permissions than a normal user; that is why I see what project owners would see for their own projects.]*

Comment: Eureka! Thanks, that was driving me nuts. I had all available permissions when it was a sandbox. I guess I wasn't given that last one after promoting to contrib. Since I can Administer Maintainers I just gave myself that last permission and all is fixed.

Comment: do you know if it's possible to change the owner of a project is that just stuck for eternity?

Comment: It's possible, if you follow https://www.drupal.org/node/251466#procedure---own-project.

Comment: Cool, thank ya!